# What can we do about the performance issues we are experiencing with the resumable upload API using MS Graph Java SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

We are using the Java SDK to first create an upload session, then upload the document. We are currently uploading in chunks of 10 MB (as recommended by public documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0), but we are noticing that each chunk takes ~10 seconds.

Based on what is logged by the SDK, it seems like the time is taken up by the network.

Here is a snippet of logs when uploading a chunk:

```
13-Jan-2020 02:41:23.503 INFO [http-DS0-1364-37-1578883281173] com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger.logDebug Starting to send request, URL https://obfuscated.com/sites
/blur/_api/v2.0/drives/12345/items/12345/uploadSession?guid='blur'&path='blur.docx'&overwrite=False&rename=True&dc=0&tempauth=blur
13-Jan-2020 02:41:23.504 INFO [http-DS0-1364-37-1578883281173] com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger.logDebug Request Method PUT
13-Jan-2020 02:41:23.504 INFO [http-DS0-1364-37-1578883281173] com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger.logDebug Sending byte[] as request body
13-Jan-2020 02:41:33.018 INFO [http-DS0-1364-37-1578883281173] com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger.logDebug Response code 202, Accepted
13-Jan-2020 02:41:33.018 INFO [http-DS0-1364-37-1578883281173] com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger.logDebug StatefulResponse is handling the HTTP response.
13-Jan-2020 02:41:33.018 INFO [http-DS0-1364-37-1578883281173] com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger.logDebug Chunk bytes has been accepted by the server.
13-Jan-2020 02:41:33.019 INFO [http-DS0-1364-37-1578883281173] com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger.logDebug Deserializing type UploadSession
```

Is this expected? Is there any way to perform the upload faster?